# Mule Munit Failure to find com.mulesoft.mule.distributions:mule-runtime-impl-bom:pom:4.2.0

Tags: maven, mule, mule-esb, mulesoft

I am when compile the sample Mule application its giving bellow error message. Any help this dependency issue `Failure to find com.mulesoft.mule.distributions:mule-runtime-impl-bom:pom:4.2.0 in`

**full error message**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:2.1.5:test (test) on project helloworld: Build Fail: MUnit Tests Failed
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start embedded container
[ERROR]     at org.mule.runtime.module.embedded.internal.DefaultEmbeddedContainerBuilder$1.start(DefaultEmbeddedContainerBuilder.java:169)
[ERROR]     at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.run(RemoteRunner.java:119)
[ERROR]     at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.main(RemoteRunner.java:88)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find embedded container bom artifact
[ERROR]     at org.mule.runtime.module.embedded.internal.MavenContainerClassLoaderFactory.create(MavenContainerClassLoaderFactory.java:83)
[ERROR]     at org.mule.runtime.module.embedded.internal.DefaultEmbeddedContainerBuilder$1.start(DefaultEmbeddedContainerBuilder.java:146)
[ERROR]     ... 2 more
[ERROR] Caused by: org.mule.maven.client.api.BundleDependenciesResolutionException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find com.mulesoft.mule.distributions:mule-runtime-impl-bom:pom:4.2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-central has elapsed or updates are forced
[ERROR]     at org.mule.maven.client.internal.AetherMavenClient.resolveBundleDescriptorDependencies(AetherMavenClient.java:261)
[ERROR]     at org.mule.maven.client.internal.AetherMavenClient.resolveBundleDescriptorDependencies(AetherMavenClient.java:232)
[ERROR]     at org.mule.runtime.module.embedded.internal.MavenContainerClassLoaderFactory.create(MavenContainerClassLoaderFactory.java:55)
[ERROR]     ... 3 more
[ERROR] Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find com.mulesoft.mule.distributions:mule-runtime-impl-bom:pom:4.2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-central has elapsed or updates are forced
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
[ERROR]     at org.mule.maven.client.internal.AetherMavenClient.resolveBundleDescriptorDependencies(AetherMavenClient.java:243)
[ERROR]     ... 5 more
[ERROR] Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find com.mulesoft.mule.distributions:mule-runtime-impl-bom:pom:4.2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-central has elapsed or updates are forced
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:231)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
[ERROR]     at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
[ERROR]     ... 9 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:2.1.5:test (test) on project helloworld: Build Fail
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Build Fail
    at org.mule.munit.mojo.exceptions.MojoExecutionExceptionFactory.buildException (MojoExecutionExceptionFactory.java:86)
    at org.mule.munit.MUnitMojo.doExecute (MUnitMojo.java:291)
    at org.mule.munit.MUnitMojo.execute (MUnitMojo.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: MUnit Tests Failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start embedded container
    at org.mule.runtime.module.embedded.internal.DefaultEmbeddedContainerBuilder$1.start(DefaultEmbeddedContainerBuilder.java:169)
    at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.run(RemoteRunner.java:119)
    at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.main(RemoteRunner.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find embedded container bom artifact
    at org.mule.runtime.module.embedded.internal.MavenContainerClassLoaderFactory.create(MavenContainerClassLoaderFactory.java:83)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.embedded.internal.DefaultEmbeddedContainerBuilder$1.start(DefaultEmbeddedContainerBuilder.java:146)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.mule.maven.client.api.BundleDependenciesResolutionException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find com.mulesoft.mule.distributions:mule-runtime-impl-bom:pom:4.2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.mule.maven.client.internal.AetherMavenClient.resolveBundleDescriptorDependencies(AetherMavenClient.java:261)
    at org.mule.maven.client.internal.AetherMavenClient.resolveBundleDescriptorDependencies(AetherMavenClient.java:232)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.embedded.internal.MavenContainerClassLoaderFactory.create(MavenContainerClassLoaderFactory.java:55)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find com.mulesoft.mule.distributions:mule-runtime-impl-bom:pom:4.2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
    at org.mule.maven.client.internal.AetherMavenClient.resolveBundleDescriptorDependencies(AetherMavenClient.java:243)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find com.mulesoft.mule.distributions:mule-runtime-impl-bom:pom:4.2.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 9 more

    at org.mule.munit.MUnitMojo.doExecute (MUnitMojo.java:292)
    at org.mule.munit.MUnitMojo.execute (MUnitMojo.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:
```

347)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dependency seems to be in the MuleSoft Enterprise repository (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb#referencing-mulesofts-enterprise-repositories). Note that you'll need to be a customer to have credentials for it.